# ASP.NET Get the List View value and post to textbox

Tags: asp.net

ASPX

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" GroupItemCount="2" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder1"
                    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
           <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
       </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
             <table border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; border: double 2px #04AFEF; background-color: #B0E2F5">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <b><span class="city"><%# Eval("Name") %></span><br /></b>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' > </asp:Label>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <b><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" /> <%# Eval("Image")%><br />
                 </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="someButtonID" Text ="SomeText" CommandName="SomeCommandName" />
                  </td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </td>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I want to know what to do. I'm just a beginner programmer. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you please explain further what it is you want to actually do.

Comment: Specifically which list view value and what text box? What triggers the action? Do you want to do this with a post back via asp.net, or do it client side with javascript/jQuery ?